# Vue Как передать в select значения с сервера

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть форма с настройками пользователя, где есть селекты. С сервера должно прийти значение этого селекта

Пробовал байндить selected, передавал в него true, но он не отображается

```
                   <div class="input-field">
                     <select id="role" v-model='role'>
                       <option disabled :selected="!role">Enter Role User</option>
                       <option value="admin" :selected="{selected: role === 'admin'}">Admin</option>
                       <option value="manager" :selected="role === 'manager'">Manager</option>
                       <option value="author" :selected="role === 'author'">Author</option>
                       <option value="user" :selected="role === 'user'">User</option>
                     </select>
                   </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Role это string
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой scripts

```
<script>
import Header from '@/admin/components/header/Header'
import Section from "@/admin/components/Section"
import Loader from "@/admin/components/Loader"

import Save from '@/admin/components/Save'
import DefaultWidget from "@/admin/components/widget/Default"
import ImageWidget from "@/admin/components/widget/Image"

// Validator
import {required, email} from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {
  name: 'Profile',
  data: () => ({
    breadcrumb: [{label: 'Dashboard', url: '/'}, {label: 'Users', url: '/users'}, {label: 'Profile'}],
    loader: true,
    nickname: '',
    name: '',
    surname: '',
    email: '',
    biography: '',
    avatar: '',
    role: '',
    language: '',
  }),
  validations: {
    email: {required, email},
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.loader = false

    const nickname = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login')).login
    await this.$store.dispatch('getUser', nickname)

    try {
      const user = this.$store.getters.getUser

      this.name = user.name
      this.surname = user.surname
      this.biography = user.biography
      this.nickname = user.nickname
      this.email = user.email
      this.avatar = user.avatar
      this.role = user.role
      this.displayName = user.displayName
      this.language = user.language
    } catch (err) {
      await this.$error(err)
    }

    console.log(this.role)
    await $('select').material_select();
    await $('textarea#biography').characterCounter();

    // Fixed Materialize Select
    const self = this;
    $('#displayName').on('change', function () {
      self.$emit("change_name", this.value)
    });
    $('#role').on('change', function () {
      self.$emit("change_role", this.value)
    });
    $('#language').on('change', function () {
      self.$emit("change_language", this.value)
    });

    self.$on("change_name", function (data) {
      this.displayName = data
    });
    self.$on("change_role", function (data) {
      this.role = data
    });
    self.$on("change_language", function (data) {
      this.language = data
    });
  },
  methods: {
    async saveSetting() {
      const nickname = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('login')).login
      if (this.$v.$invalid) {
        this.$v.$touch()
        return
      }

      const formData = {
        name: this.name,
        surname: this.surname,
        email: this.email,
        biography: this.biography,
        role: this.role,
        language: this.language
      }

      this.$store.commit('setUser', formData)

      try {
        await this.$store.dispatch('setUser', nickname)
        this.$message('Настройки пременены')
      } catch (err) {
        if(typeof err === "object") {
          Object.entries(err).forEach(error => this.$message(`[${error[0].toUpperCase()}] ${error[1]}`))
          return
        }

        await this.$warn(err)
      }
    },
  },
  components: {
    Header, Section, Save, DefaultWidget, ImageWidget, Loader
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    $('select').material_select('destroy');
  }
}
</script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `v-model='role'` достаточно. `:selected ...` нужно удалить.

Comment: PS. Предполагаю, что role - это строка "admin/manager/...". Если объект с uuid и каким-нибудь name, то - другим способом. Если не сработает что я написал выше, покажите что такое role - тип, пример.

Comment: Я точно не помню, но оно вроде работало раньше

Comment: Если `await $('select').material_select();` убрать, то есть использовать встроенный select  - работает? Тогда проблема в материал селект, поищите версию для вью, либо пример интеграции с вью. jQuery напрямую оперирует DOM, а VUE - имеет shadow dom.

Comment: PS. Похоже, решение вот в этом: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33704122/9435985

Comment: Ага, это materialize виноват, дефолтный работает как надо, приходится костылять(

Comment: Посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704122/vuejs-materializecss-select-field. Если коротко, то придется кидать события VueJS => material_select и назад, чтобы синхронизировать. Либо найдите Vue-версию, аналогичную этому кастомизатору по функционалу. Так будет проще, нужно будет только стили поправить.

Comment: Сработала магия, добавил костыль на role, ниже у меня есть language, добавил перед вызовом плагина, language стал как надо

Comment: Надо лишь дать materialize время подумать await setTimeout(() => {}, 0) Перед объявлением плагина

Comment: Я видел ваше решение. Оно плохое. 1) скорее всего materialize назад не кинет во VueJS значение для модели, поэтому после переключения стилизованного select значение во Vue не поменяется, проверьте через плагин для отладки Vue Devtools 2) `switch (listRole) {` - это просто ужасно

Comment: Уже нашел получше, переместить объявление плагина к конец event loop. Materialize не успевает принять данные от сервера и для него role пустой

Answer (score 0):

```
               <div class="input-field">
                 <select id="role" v-model='role'>
                   <option disabled value="">Enter Role User</option>
                   <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                   <option value="manager">Manager</option>
                   <option value="author">Author</option>
                   <option value="user">User</option>
                 </select>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Виноват materialize

Вот мой костыль, может кому поможет

Добавил ref к селекту и ищу все лишки и switch добавляю классы

Есть решение по меньше

```
    await setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('sdsadsa')
    }, 0)

    await $('select').material_select();
    await $('textarea#biography').characterCounter();
```

Костыль

```
                    <div class="input-field" ref="role">
                      <select id="role" v-model='role'>
                        <option disabled value="">Enter Role User</option>
                        <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                        <option value="manager">Manager</option>
                        <option value="author">Author</option>
                        <option value="user">User</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
```

```
    async setRole() {
      const role = this.role
      const listRole = await this.$refs.role.getElementsByTagName('li')

      switch (listRole) {
        case role === 'admin':
          listRole[1].className = 'active selected'
          break
        case role === 'manager':
          listRole[2].className = 'active selected'
          break
        case role === 'author':
          listRole[3].className = 'active selected'
          break
        case role === 'user':
          listRole[3].className = 'active selected'
          break
      }
    },
```